# Optimization just by having data without accessing to objective function (Data-driven optimization)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

Suppose we have some operational data (Temperature, pressure, output power, etc.) of a steam power plant.

Without accessing the mathematical formulation of the system, is it possible to do optimization?

Let's give you a simple example:

By having the following figure, and also each data of the points, could we optimize the problem within the 18 to 25 range and find 20 as the optimum point? suppose the data between 19 to 21 have not been captured by experimental tests.

[image]

Comment: You're gonna need to give us a lot more information than this, what, how, why, etc..

Comment: I've edited the question. I want to know if data-driven optimization is possible or there isn't such a concept? I couldn't find enough data on the internet.

Comment: I found that machine learning is intrinsically an optimization problem itself and it can't be used for an optimization problem...is it true? or there is anoter way to do this?

Comment: This belongs under the term of "function approximation", which a lot of statistical models try to solve. In your case, for this specific plot, this looks like it can be solved with linear regression and maybe a quadratic term. Most of statistics is about optimization, i.e. usually in the form of fitting some point/line/space to your data such that it fits "well".

Comment: I know that it's a super complex problem, but how siemens-optimization-like-problems could be solved? Do they fit a function first and then optimize such problems? Link: https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2022/03/22/siemens-gamesa-wind-farms-digital-twins/

Comment: I have no idea what NVIDIA did, they don't go into details in the article you linked, but it looks like they used simulations, lots of them. Whatever the case, this is a completely different and unrelated question to your original question and it doesn't belong here. A linear model, which I suggested above, is quite simple to use and doesn't require a cluster of computers.

Comment: I tried to highly simply the problem to be understandable for the community, in real situations, there are several input data and two or three output data. What I understand is first we have to approximate the function of the problem using the data, then apply optimization, Is that true?